# Azure Cosmos DB MongoDB API 4.0 transactions exception handling

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure-cosmosdb, mongodb-.net-driver, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

### Description

I am working on an application which needs to handle synchronization on updates made to MongoDB documents. For this purpose I am using Azure Cosmos DB MongoDB API 4.0 which supports [multi-document transactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/use-multi-document-transactions).

### Issue

Occasionally, I get the following exception during updates within a transaction:

```
MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command update failed: Error=112, Details='Response status code does not indicate success: Conflict (409); Substatus: 5403; ActivityId: 88cc0f1f-708b-4c42-9ba7-70e367f16fe3; Reason: ({
  "Errors": [
    "Conflicting request to resource has been attempted. Retry to avoid conflicts."
  ]
});.
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandUsingCommandMessageWireProtocol`1.ProcessResponse(ConnectionId connectionId, CommandMessage responseMessage)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandUsingCommandMessageWireProtocol`1.ExecuteAsync(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.Server.ServerChannel.ExecuteProtocolAsync[TResult](IWireProtocol`1 protocol, ICoreSession session, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.RetryableWriteOperationExecutor.ExecuteAsync[TResult](IRetryableWriteOperation`1 operation, RetryableWriteContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.BulkUnmixedWriteOperationBase`1.ExecuteBatchAsync(RetryableWriteContext context, Batch batch, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.BulkUnmixedWriteOperationBase`1.ExecuteBatchesAsync(RetryableWriteContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.BulkMixedWriteOperation.ExecuteBatchAsync(RetryableWriteContext context, Batch batch, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.BulkMixedWriteOperation.ExecuteAsync(IWriteBinding binding, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.OperationExecutor.ExecuteWriteOperationAsync[TResult](IWriteBinding binding, IWriteOperation`1 operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.ExecuteWriteOperationAsync[TResult](IClientSessionHandle session, IWriteOperation`1 operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.BulkWriteAsync(IClientSessionHandle session, IEnumerable`1 requests, BulkWriteOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionBase`1.UpdateOneAsync(FilterDefinition`1 filter, UpdateDefinition`1 update, UpdateOptions options, Func`3 bulkWriteAsync)
```

I tried retrying the failed update operations several times (with delays of 1000ms) without any luck.

Each retry ends up with the same exception message.

Finally, the exception message changes to:

```
MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command update failed: Error=2, Details='Response status code does not indicate success: BadRequest (400); Substatus: 1101; ActivityId: bcb86266-aa9a-4a2d-9841-7f451d6c72ee; Reason: (Message: {"Errors":["Transaction is not active"]}
```

I believe the last exception is different, because the transaction times-out (timeout=5seconds by the documentation).

### Question

1. How should one gracefully recover from exceptions that occur during multi-document transaction when using Azure Cosmos DB MongoDB API?
2. Can anyone provide any additional information about listed exception messages? For example: how to debug, handle, recover from them? (Any information is more than welcome)

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty spot on with diagnosing the errors. Azure Cosmos DB API for MongoDB has [documentation listing common errors and solutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-troubleshoot).

(1) 112 errors occur when another transaction or write operation is utilizing the same document. Retrying the operation until it succeeds is the recommended solution.

(2) As you mentioned, the second error - "transaction is not active" indicates the 5 sec timeout has been exceeded. Would it be possible to limit the scope of operations being done within the multi-document transaction?

Another possibility is that the operations are taking longer than expected if they are being throttled (and retried server-side) due to an insufficient number of RUs (throughput) available. A good way to check for this is to see if the Normalized RU Consumption is hitting 100% and [server-side-retry is enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/prevent-rate-limiting-errors) (it's enabled by default). If this is the case, increasing the number of RUs (throughput) should solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the end, I went on with a combination of retry policy on individual updates and transaction it self. [MongoDb documentation has some ideas on retrying transcations](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/core/transactions)